# Setting up Mimetype when using TemplateView in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Does anyboy know how do I set the desired mimetype when using TemplateView, as in:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='staticpages/test.html')),
```

In this case, I want to set the mimtype as "text/plain"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

## For Django >= 1.5

TemplateView accepts a content_type argument.

Coping example from @Meilo

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='staticpages/test.html', content_type='text/plain')),
```

## For Django < 1.5

I think that just calling TemplateView.as_view() is not posible but maybe i missed it (from the source),
but you can do your own class

```
class TextTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response_kwargs['content_type'] = 'text/plain'
        return super(TemplateView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

You can take a look to:

django.template.response => TemplateResponse
django.views.generic.base => TemplateView

And if you need something more dynamic:

```
from django.utils.decorators import classonlymethod


class ContentTypeTemplateView(TemplateView):

    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, content_type='text/plain', **initargs):
        setattr(cls, 'content_type', content_type)
        return super(ContentTypeTemplateView, cls).as_view(**initargs)

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        response_kwargs['content_type'] = self.content_type
        return super(ContentTypeTemplateView, self).render_to_response(context, **response_kwargs)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ContentTypeTemplateView.as_view(content_type='text/plain',
                                               template_name='staticpages/test.html'),
        name='index'),
)
```

### Using a Mixin

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


class ContentTypeMixin(object):

    content_type = None

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        if not self.content_type:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "MimeTypeMixin rquires a definition of content_type")
        response_kwargs['content_type'] = self.content_type
        return super(ContentTypeMixin, self).render_to_response(context,
                                                             **response_kwargs)


class MyTxtView(ContentTypeMixin, TemplateView):
    content_type = 'text/plain'
    ....
```

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use `content_type` as the parameter, as `mimetype` [is deprecated in favor of it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__init__).

Comment: you are rigth I will change it

Answer (score 19):

In Django 1.5 the **content_type** argument in the TemplateView adds the same functionality that was in the function-based view before. That makes it easier to set the desired mimetype:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='staticpages/test.html', content_type='text/plain')),
```

Answer (score 4):

I know that you ask for setting a content type with TemplateView, but I will give you different answer which I think that will be more clean and can be used in Django versions lower than 1.5.

```
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', 'django.shortcuts.render', kwargs={
        'template_name': 'robots.txt',
        'content_type': 'text/plain',
    })
```

With this approach you don't need to import anything or to subclass `TemplateView` and make ugly overwrites of some methods. You can simply use the old technique with function based views.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is to subclass `TemplateView` and override the `render_to_response()` method:

```
class StaticPagesTest(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'staticpages/test.html'

    def render_to_response(self, context, **kwargs):
        return super(StaticPagesTest, self).render_to_response(context,
                     mimetype='text/plain', **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sacabuche has a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to extend the TemplateView, you can extend the TemplateResponse to set the mimetype:

```
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

class TextResponse(TemplateResponse):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['mimetype'] = 'text/plain'
        return super(TextResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then pass it as the template_class to the TemplateView

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.simple',
    (r'^robots\.txt$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', response_class=TextResponse)),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is solved for 1.5, but the application I am working in is 1.4.

I had an issue with two url patterns in a row using sacabuche's answer:

```
url(r'^playlist1\.m3u$', ContentTypeTemplateView.as_view(template_name='playlist1.m3u', content_type='audio/x-mpegurl')),
url(r'^playlist2\.pls$', ContentTypeTemplateView.as_view(template_name='playlist2.pls', content_type='audio/x-scpls'))
```

I found playlist1 would return the correct template, but with playlist2's content type!  Playlist2 was ok.  Adding a 3rd url pattern with a content-type of 'foo' would cause all playlist views to return with content-type 'foo'.

I ended up using the render method instead with good results:

urls:

```
url(r'^playlist1\.m3u$', 'content_type_to_template', {'template_name': 'playlist1.m3u', 'content_type': 'audio/x-mpegurl'}),
url(r'^playlist2\.pls$', 'content_type_to_template', {'template_name': 'playlist2.pls', 'content_type':'audio/x-scpls'})
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def content_type_to_template(request, template_name='', content_type='text/plain'):
    return render(request, template_name, content_type=content_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

**A simple example of how change content type of a TemplateView:**

```
#views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home/index.html"
    content_type = 'text/html'

# urls.py
url(r'^home/$', HomeView.as_view(), name='home_page'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'^test/(?P<template>.*)', lambda request, template: TemplateView.as_view(template_name=template)(request)),
```